# Connection String is not working on AWS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a web API application on visual studio 2017. I have published the web application on my local IIS and everything is working fine, but when I publish it to IIS on AWS instance (with windows server 2012) the connection string keep giving me errors and could not manage to connect correctly.

The connection string is:

```
<add name="TouchlessDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/; provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=WIN-FBNRCF4UTP3\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=TouchlessDB;integrated security=True;User Id=sa; Password=Password01;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and here is the error I am getting from the browser:

```
{"$id":"1","message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The underlying provider failed on Open.","exceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException","stackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Touchless.Web.Api.Common.Filters.BasicAuthorizeAttribute.HandleAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext, AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader) in D:\\Touchless.Web.Api\\WEB-API\\Touchless.Web.Api\\Touchless.Web.Api.Common\\Filters\\BasicAuthorizeAttribute.cs:line 60\r\n   at Touchless.Web.Api.Common.Filters.BasicAuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) in D:\\Touchless.Web.Api\\WEB-API\\Touchless.Web.Api\\Touchless.Web.Api.Common\\Filters\\BasicAuthorizeAttribute.cs:line 49\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()","innerException":{"$id":"2","message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Cannot open database \"TouchlessDB\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\\WebAPI'.","exceptionType":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","stackTrace":"   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()"}}
```

Could you please help me to solve it?

Comment: if `WIN-FBNRCF4UTP3` is your local database server then  AWS machine can not access it over the internet. that's why you are getting this error. You need to have a database server which can be accessed by the AWS machine. AWS has RDS service using which you can setup a database server on AWS and your application can connect to it when it is deployed on AWs.

Comment: WIN-FBNRCF4UTP3 is the name of AWS server not my local server

Comment: Try removing `Integrated security=True` from the connection string.

Comment: It is working now :) Thank you so much. May I know why with Integrated security option it is not working?

Comment: With `Integrated security=True` current Windows account credentials to connect to the database on db server. Since the Db server and Application server are not part of the same domain on AWS in your case they won't recognize the user's of each other. When you remove this, username and password provided in the connection string are used for connection.

Comment: I got it thanks again :)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Please post that as answer before anyone else post your answer as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing Integrated security=True from the connection string solved my problem. Thanks @ChetanRanpariya